# Finding specifics on generic motors; probably 200 steps per revolution

Tags: z-axis, klipper, linux

I have been reading the Klipper docs and currently, I am trying to attain a theory on why my T8 leadscrew is not moving the Z-axis gantry.

I used to have a "T7" or 7 mm rod that my gantry was handled by at the time...

1. Since the "upgrade," I have noticed that my gantry does not move.
2. I have a cartesian style printer w/ T8 leadscrew for the gantry/Z-axis movement.
3. Since the upgrade, I have also noticed a slight hum that has been resolved w/ `rotation_distance` from the klipper docs.
4. I erased my config, had to start over, and have a new OS.
5. The motors for X and Y move just fine, i.e. exactly like they are supposed to move.

```
[probe]
pin: ar100:PH4
x_offset: 0.0
y_offset: 0.0
z_offset: 1.1
speed: 3
lift_speed: 6

[stepper_z]
step_pin: ar100:PL6
dir_pin: ar100:PE10
endstop_pin: probe:z_virtual_endstop
rotation_distance: 8
microsteps: 16
position_min: 0
position_max: 152.0
homing_speed: 8.0
```

In the above snippet, this is part of my main config reference, I have a `[probe]` and this `[probe]` has `speed` and `lift_speed` which require specific options.

My notes are gone. I cannot calculate lift speed any longer due to lack of instruction and I am thinking, from what I can remember, `speed` is traversing the XY plane.

Answer (score 0):

The Klipper documentation and configurations were not at fault as I figured.

I went through the documentation, set up instances of different configuration options, and readjusted `printer.cfg` options.

Anyway, it turns out the lead screw was faulty and bent. Calculating Klipper configurations will NOT prove useful with a bent lead screw.

Also, because of the rotation of the lead screw per one turn, I had to adjust the `rotation_distance` in the `printer.cfg` file.

Also...rotation_distance for XY, Z, and E all need separate-real values that are configured and this set of examples can be found in many places online like w/ the Klipper docs, https://all3dp.com/, and the reprap wiki.